# Possible to gather telemetry from InterSystems Cache using Microsoft Azure's Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, intersystems-cache, performance-monitor

I'm working on an Azure Application Insights dashboard for a system involving an InterSystems Cache database.

Is it possible to make Application Insights "aware" of a Cache database, in the way it's possible with our .NET code and other MS products on the server?

Lacking any quick-and-easy way, are there any Cache performance counters that might appear in the standard Windows Performance Monitor tool?  (Because it's possible to gather these into AppInsights.)

Lacking *both* of these...are there any best practices otherwise?

Comment: You can always try to hook it up to a logging system If InterSystems Cache provides that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics

Comment: I would suggest asking about it at [InterSystems Developer community portal](https://community.intersystems.com/) - maybe some of the developers or even InterSystem staff already faced this issue too.

Comment: Yeah. Application Insights provide integrating with different runtimes, and if InterSystems support it then you can very well get the information you need.

Comment: If it supports SNMP, that may be the easiest way as Cache supports that out of the box.